# JSP Servlet dynamic change page content via ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

Is there a way to let my page using ajax update a certain part content on my jsp webpage when the database change?

Currently I have:
 
1. db.java - a class to connect to database and query out the data I want
2. admin.jsp -  a jsp page to display those data I want

My question:
How to using JSP and servlet automatically and dynamically update a page content while database changes, I know how to use JQuery ajax call servlet, but to achieved this, the only way I can get is set a time interval and loop repeating call ajax function, is this way workable ? or there are others better methods to do it?

Comment: May be by using websockets (or long polling).

Comment: ㄴ he is right. looping ajax is mainstream. if you want to real time update, you must follow about websocket.

Comment: @Tiny is there an good example how to use that websocket to make a realtime update?

Comment: Pardon ? I have not yet put websockets into practice.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing similer thing using jquery .load().. I have a struts2 action which is returning a VO ,which is binded with JSP view . i am calling same action via jquery .load() and updating JSP div.

I am using a polling timer which is handled in javascript to trigger this .

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Regds,
Amit